# Unable to send e-mail

Tags: 7

i want to create a new user, for this , i have done the following things.
1.Installed SMTP module through drush
2.Installed sendmail through apt-get
3.and created the new user, when i trying to create a user it shows the error as mentioned in image.
Please someone help me to get out of it.[image: The error message]

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Drupal Answers. I believe this is out of scope. [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) would be a more appropriate place to search, there may even be answers for that like [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/54960/how-do-i-set-up-an-email-server/55027#55027). Also take a read at [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MailServer).

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-postfix-on-ubuntu-12-04

Answer (score 0):

You dont necessary need the SSMTP module.

I think this is a bad configuration with your local environment. For testing purpose you should consider using Gmail.

> Debian/Ubuntu users can Install with this command or click here to
>   open up apt:
>
> `sudo apt-get install ssmtp`
>
> We need to then need to edit, `‘/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf’`:

```
root=username@gmail.com mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587 rewriteDomain= hostname=username@gmail.com UseSTARTTLS=YES AuthUser=username AuthPass=password FromLineOverride=YES
```

> Then add each account that you want to be able to send mail from by
>   editing, ‘/etc/ssmtp/revaliases‘:

```
root:username@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
localusername:username@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
```

If you do not want to used Gmail here is another [tutorial](http://codekarate.com/blog/sending-emails-your-ubuntu-drupal-development-environment-2-minutes) with an alternative Sendgrid.